# What is the best way to set one python class attribute from another class?

Tags: python, class, dependency-injection, attributes

What is the best way to add the class Defaults into class Primary? The Defaults are to be shared among all Primary class instances. I will iterate through lists to create Primary class objects and will need to change the Defaults between different lists. All of these work but it seems like the first method is less readable and the second method would cause every Primary class to create a separate copy of the default variables. The third way is using inheritance, which I have read is not preferred over composition. I feel like there must be a reason to use one over another.

Method 1: Create class attribute

```
class Primary():
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

class Defaults():
    def __init__(self, name, path):
        self.name = name
        self.path = path

inst_default = Defaults("myfile", "/tmp/mydir/")
Primary.default = inst_default
inst_primary = Primary("https://www.someurl")
```

Method 2: Create instance attribute

```
class Primary():
    def __init__(self, url, inst_default):
        self.url = url
        self.default = inst_default

class Defaults():
    def __init__(self, name, path):
        self.name = name
        self.path = path

inst_default = Defaults("myfile", "/tmp/mydir/")
inst_primary = Primary("https://www.someurl", inst_default)
```

Testing Method 1 & 2:

```
print(inst_primary.url)
print(inst_primary.default.path)
print(inst_primary.default.name)
print(inst_default.name)
```

Method 3: Inheritance of class attribute

```
class Defaults():
    def __init__(self, name, path):
        Defaults.name = name
        Defaults.path = path

class Primary(Defaults):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.name = Defaults.name
        self.path = Defaults.path

inst_default = Defaults("myfile", "/tmp/mydir/")
inst_primary = Primary("https://www.someurl")
```

Testing Method 3:

```
print(inst_primary.url)
print(inst_primary.path)
print(inst_primary.name)
print(inst_default.name)
```

Comment: That depends on how the default values are intended to be used: are they instance-specfic or meant to be used by any instance? They may even be better passed as values to a specific instance method at call time. Inheritance is almost certainly *not* the correct approach, though.

Comment: @chepner They are used by all instances. Also, I had some errors in method 3 and just fixed them.